# How to prevent scrolling of window with libgdx gwt game

Tags: html, gwt, iframe, libgdx

I am exporting a gwt game from libgdx to Kongregate using the kongregate shell which creates a iframe and puts the game in it. From looking around, I found out a tidbit about putting window.focus() to let the game actually pick up the keyboard input but when i use the arrow keys, it scrolls the actual browser window as well making it very annoying.

is there any way to ignore browser when the iframe is in focus to avoid this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have had this issue when publishing games on my own website, I asked on the libGDX GitHub Issue Tracker and I got this response on the [issue](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/issues/2584).

Summarizing what maximojr told me, you need to add an extra function to the script that reads:

```
function preventUseOfDefaultKeys(event) { // You can change the function name
    if(event.keyCode == 38) { // 38 would be the up arrow
        event.preventDefualt();
    }
}
```

Then, in the **body** tag of your HTML file (since this is an iframe I'm not sure how well this will work, but it's worth a try) instead of `<body>` write `<body onkeydown="preventUseOfDefaultKeys(event);" >`. This should work, although I've encountered issues with certain keys on my system.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I've faced the same problem. There goes the solution I got.

1. Create a text field at the begin of `<body>` tag in the index.html:

`<input type="text" id="shazam" style="position: absolute; left: 50%; z-index: -1; border-color: transparent; outline: none; color: transparent; background-color: transparent;" />`

The 'position' absolute means it will ignore other elements, the 'left' will put it (almost) at the center of the window and the 'z-index' will render it first, leting other elements over this (in this case the canvas generated by libgdx). None outline and colors set to transparent just to make sure this input will be invisible.

2. At `<head>` tag put this script:

`<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onkeydown = function(e) {
        if(e.keyCode == 32) {
            document.getElementById("shazam").focus();
        }
    };
    window.onscroll = function(e){
        document.getElementById("shazam").style.top=window.pageYOffset+"px";
    };
</script>`

This will disable the scrolling down on space but also anything outside the canvas will not receive the space key.
I tested only on Google Chrome.

I know, this is a ugly workaround, but... well, works.

----edit

Now the window won't suddenly scroll up when space is pressed after the window is scrolled with mouse.